# Why is Jimmy angry at the flag flying at half mast?

Tags: the-irishman

In the Irishman (2019), after JFK was shot dead, after he exited international brotherhood of teamsters, Jimmy sees the US flag flying at half-mast on top of the building:

> Jimmy: Son of a bitch.

Jimmy runs to the top of this building and sees the US flag rising. He then thanks Eric:

> Jimmy: Good Eric. Thank you very much.

Why is Jimmy angry at the flag flying at half-mast?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why people think this is so unclear it needs closing.  I have attempted to make it a little more understandable but I think it was pretty clear before.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.dailypublic.com/articles/11222019/film-review-irishman :

> **He so detests the Kennedys**, whom he feel he put in the White House, that when he sees the American flag over the Teamsters’ headquarters lowered to half-mast after JFK’s assassination, he orders it run back up.